# Camel @EndpointInject annotation ignored, uri exists in camelContext at runtime

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel

I'm trying to configure a unit test using @EndpointInject, but the injection is always null. If I iterate the endpoints from the camel context I can see my endpoint, and even manually inject the endpoint.

How can I get the @EndpointInject annotation to work?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TrackingBrokerRouteBuilderTest2 extends CamelTestSupport {

  @EndpointInject(uri = "direct:my.endpoint")
  private ProducerTemplate           myEndpoint;

  // This should not be needed.
  @Before
  public void setUp()  {
    for (Endpoint e : camelContext.getEndpoints()) {
      System.out.println("  --> " + e.getEndpointUri());
      // With this next block, my test works.
      if (myEndpoint == null && e.getEndpointUri().equals("direct:my.endpoint")) {
        myEndpoint = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        myEndpoint.setDefaultEndpoint(e);
      }
    }
  }

  @Test
  @DirtiesContext
  public void testBrokerEndpoints() throws Exception {

    // Check that a bean method is called later on.    
    EasyMock.expect(beanFunction.call(EasyMock.anyObject())
        .andReturn(null).once();
    EasyMock.replay(trackingPayloadValidator);

    // Send a message, myEndpoint is null unless I manually init it.
    myEndpoint.sendBody("test");

    // Test succeeds if I manually init it.
    EasyMock.verify(trackingPayloadValidator);
  }
}
```